# is it possible to mix chipsets

Tags: computer-architecture

I'm designing a home made game console motherboard, and want to integrate the ATI Mobility Radeon 9000 GPU in it. The problem is, the Northbridge I picked only supports PCI Express, and the GPU uses AGP x4. So I found a second Northbridge chip designed for AGP, but as far as I know, is not designed for my processor (Intel Dual Core). I'm thinking about attaching both Northbridges to the CPU, having the AGP one solely control the GPU, and the other control everything else. So here are my questions: 1) Is this method practical, as in, is it possible to wire everything correctly so they work, 2) will the AGP chip work without having RAM attached to it, 3) If my method won't work, is there a way of bridging the PCI Express interface to the AGP x4 interface?

My two Northbridge chips are the GL960 for the main chip, and the 855GM for the AGP. I don't want to get different chips, because I have these two on hand from scrapped laptops.

Comment: What do the datasheets say? Note that AGP is a type of PCI, so you could use a PCIe to PCI bridge to connect the AGP video chip. If you are asking questions like whether the GPU will work without VRAM (is that really what you are asking?) and whether it is possible to "wire this up", I humbly suggest you might be getting in over your head. If not, please clarify the question.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Well, The answer below says that attaching two chips on the FSB like that won't work, so I'm saving the Radeon for something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a really bad idea.  It's highly unlikely to work as the front side bus is not designed to be split that way.  Also, those two chips are designed to run at completely different FSB frequencies and so there may be little hope of putting them on the same bus, even if the bus architecture supported it.  The chipset is the the bridge between the processor, the peripherals, and RAM.  One of the main issues that you would run in to with that configuration is that DMA will not be possible for the graphics card as the chipsets are designed to do DMA to the locally attached memory, not across the FSB.  A much better idea would be to get a PCIe to PCI bridge chip and then hang the AGP card off of this as a PCI card.  You will take a performance hit with this configuration.  Or you can try to find a different chipset that has an AGP port.  Don't bother using salvaged chips, it's going to cost you a very significant chunk of change to get the 8 to 12 layer board made up, which will completely override the cost savings of using salvaged chips.  Don't even attempt this if you're not going to get a board made - the number of pins and the signal integrity requirements will come back to bite you very, very hard.

Comment: Okay. I guess I'll just ditch the Radeon and use the integrated GPU in the GL960. And I already know about the multiple layers and signal integrity, I'll design the board and order it. Plus, I'm going to buy extras in case I destroy the salvages from desoldering them. I'm willing to take on the challenge.

Comment: Have you thought about picking up a used FPGA board with a large FPGA on it and then building the whole system inside an FPGA?  Take a look at the milkymist project, for example.  That sort of thing is an even bigger green field and has far fewer question marks than attempting to graft together a bunch of salvaged hardware.  You could even design your own CPU if you go that route.  Or you could get, say, a Zynq board such as the ZedBoard that has a built in ARM core.

Comment: The thing is, I want this console to be powerful enough to emulate almost any console, hopefully up to the PS2 generation. I also had the idea of designing a CPU, but don't know where to send my designs to get it made.

Comment: That's a pretty tall order.  It could also be a good argument for going with an FPGA.  For those older systems, it may well be possible to implement all of the console functionality on one FPGA, presuming you get one big enough.  Just load a different FPGA config for the console you want.  Otherwise, what, you would just run existing emulation software?

Comment: The thing is, FPGAs big enough to do what I intend are REALLY expensive compared to an Intel Dual Core. And I plan on having something close to different configs for each console. A base OS will detect the game you put in, or load a ROM from the hard drive, and load an emulation kernel for the console the game is for. Unless you can find a powerful FPGA that won't kill my wallet, I'm sticking with the Dual Core.

Comment: So you're not going to write your own OS or emulator, instead use a standard OS with a supervisor script of some sort that pulls up the correct emulator?

Comment: Yep. I'm also going to port some existing emulators to work with the console. And I'll have to write my own emulator for the Xbox 360, since those don't yet exist.

Comment: That makes more sense.  You mentioned wanting to write your OS, but it seems like building on top of an existing platform is a more sensible solution.  What do you need a custom motherboard for, exactly?  Have you considered using a salvaged laptop motherboard with integrated graphics?

Comment: It's more fun to make my own board. Plus it's good practice for when I enter the PC design industry.